# Maxima: Expand e to cos and i sin?

Tags: maxima

Is there a function in Maxima to expand complex exponentials to cos + i sin form by Euler?

e.g.

```
expr: %e^(%i*w);
trigsomefunctionplease(expr);
```

that would give...

```
(%o1) cos(w) + i sin(w)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) and not  [de Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), but in *Maxima* there is a [function](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_9.html#IDX261) and an [option-variable](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_9.html#IDX260)  called `demoivre`  to accomplish this.

> *Function:* **demoivre** *(expr)*
>   *Option variable:* **demoivre**
>   The function `demoivre (expr)` converts one expression without setting the global variable `demoivre`.
>
> When the variable `demoivre` is true, complex exponentials are converted into equivalent expressions in terms of circular functions: `exp (a + b*%i)` simplifies to `%e^a * (cos(b) + %i*sin(b))` if `b` is free of `%i`. `a` and `b` are not expanded.
>
> The default value of `demoivre` is `false`.
>
> `exponentialize` converts circular and hyperbolic functions to exponential form. `demoivre` and `exponentialize` cannot both be true at the same time.

Here is an example using the [Maxima Online Calculator](http://maxima-online.org/#?in=demoivre%3B%0A%25e%5E(%25i*w)%3B%0Aexpr%3A%25e%5E(%25i*w)%3B%0Ademoivre(%25e%5E(%25i*w))%3B%0Ademoivre(expr)%3B%0A%25e%5E(%25i*w)%2Cdemoivre%3Dtrue%3B%0Aexpr%2Cdemoivre%3Dtrue%3B%0A%25e%5E(%25i*w)%3B%0Ademoivre%3Atrue%3B%0A%25e%5E(%25i*w)%3B%0Aexpr%3B%0Aexpr%2Cev%3B)

```
(%i1) demoivre;
(%o1)                                false
(%i2) %e^(%i*w);
                                      %i w
(%o2)                               %e
(%i3) expr:%e^(%i*w);
                                      %i w
(%o3)                               %e
(%i4) demoivre(%e^(%i*w));
(%o4)                         %i sin(w) + cos(w)
(%i5) demoivre(expr);
(%o5)                         %i sin(w) + cos(w)
(%i6) %e^(%i*w),demoivre=true;
(%o6)                         %i sin(w) + cos(w)
(%i7) expr,demoivre=true;
(%o7)                         %i sin(w) + cos(w)
(%i8) %e^(%i*w);
                                      %i w
(%o8)                               %e
(%i9) demoivre:true;
(%o9)                                true
(%i10) %e^(%i*w);
(%o10)                        %i sin(w) + cos(w)
(%i11) expr;
                                      %i w
(%o11)                              %e
(%i12) expr,ev;
(%o12)                        %i sin(w) + cos(w)
(%i13)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!!! As an aside, and perhaps I'm wrong, but isn't DeMoivre's formula relating specifically to the relationship between raising to a power and variable multiples $(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^{n}=\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)$, i.e. a special case of Euler's formula. Shouldn't the Maxima function name relate to Euler instead?